# Is a pic 16f877a reprogrammable

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programmer

I have just finished a basic lesson in electronics, an i have become interested in micro-controller programming.  I have decided i would learn on the PIC micro-controller because it looks simple and their are many tutorials available.  When researching the pic to start with the 16f877a was recommended.  However when i was researching it I think i heard somewhere that it could not be reprogrammed.  I was wondering weather it could be reprogrammed using a pickit programmer after having previously been programmed.

Comment: Yes, its reprogrammable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"F" PICs are flash-based and hence are electrically reprogrammable. "C" PICs are OTP, but there are ways of adding programming to it as long as the firmware isn't full (see the family datasheet for details).

Answer (score 4):

While there are some exceptions, typically the following applies:

The 'F' within the part number PIC16F877A indicates it is a flash based device and is reprogrammable using ICSP techniques.

Whereas the presence of a 'C' instead of the 'F' indicate a EPROM based device which are typically One Time Programmable (OTP) devices. However, some 'C' models do provide UV erasure window which allows the device to be erased using UV light and reprogrammable once erased.

There are also 'CR' and 'CE' variants, the 'CR' type indicates a factory preprogrammed ROM device and the 'CE' indicates a 'C' type combined with an EEPROM.

Comment: One notable exception: the PIC16C84 was the first FLASH (or EEPROM, which behaves the same) device.